# Transform SELECT statememnt to JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a sql statement like :

```
SELECT a.status_id,
       (SELECT batch_name
        FROM   pf_req_batch
        WHERE  batch_id = (SELECT batch_id
                           FROM   pf_m_req_batch
                           WHERE  request_id = 282)) AS BATCH_NAME
FROM   pf_request
WHERE  request_id = 282;
```

I need to transform it using JOIN. Help, plz!

Comment: no realy sure what you mean... do you need to join 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT R.STATUS_ID, B.BATCH_NAME
FROM PF_REQUEST R
INNER JOIN PF_REQ_BATCH B ON B.BATCH_ID = R.PF_M_REQ_BATCH.BATCH_ID
WHERE REQUEST_ID=282;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT PR.STATUS_ID, PRB.BATCH_NAME as BATCH_NAME 
        FROM PF_REQ_BATCH PRB, PF_M_REQ_BATCH PMRB,PF_REQUEST PR 
        WHERE PRB.BATCH_ID = PMRB.BATCH_ID 
        AND PMRB.REQUEST_ID = PR.REQUEST_ID 
        AND PR.REQUEST_ID=282;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.STATUS_ID, b.BATCH_NAME  
FROM PF_REQUEST A  inner join PF_REQ_BATCH as b
on A.Batch_ID = b.Batch_Id
    WHERE A.REQUEST_ID=282;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three tables involved.  However, you do not seem to need `pf_req_batch` because `request_id` is in both `pf_request` and `pf_m_req_batch`.

This code is looking up the `batch_name` in the `pf_m_req_batch` table.  Here is one way to do the joins:

```
select r.status_id
from pf_request r left outer join
     pf_req_batch rb
     on r.request_id = rb.request_id 
where r.request_id = 282;
```

Note the use of the `left outer join`.  The original data keeps all matching records from `pf_request`.  This structure could produce duplicates (if there are multiple matching rows in `pf_m_req_batch`.  However, based on your original query, this shouldn't happen in your case.  If it did, you would get a subquery error (something like a subquery returning multiple rows).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table `pf_m_req_batch` is a junction table and the combination `(request_id, batch_id)` is unique, this will do:

```
SELECT r.status_id,
       b.batch_name
FROM   pf_request  r
  LEFT JOIN pf_m_req_batch  rb
    ON rb.request_id = r.request_id
  LEFT JOIN pf_req_batch  b
    ON rb.batch_id = b.batch_id 
WHERE  r.request_id = 282 ;
```

If that isn't unique (which is more probable), then this query will show many rows, one for every batch associated with request 282, while your query would throw an error.